# pandas how to apply function to groupby objects with argument

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a `df`,

```
cluster_id    memo
   1          m
   1          n
   2          m
   2          m
   2          n
   3          m
   3          m
   3          m
   3          n
   4          m
   4          n
   4          n
   4          n
```

I want to `groupby` `cluster_id` and apply the following function,

```
def valid_row_dup(df):
    num_real_invs = df[df['memo'] == 'm'].shape[0]
    num_reversals_invs = df[df['memo'] == 'n'].shape[0]

    if num_real_invs == df.shape[0]:
        return True
    elif num_reversals_invs == df.shape[0]:
        return False
    elif abs(num_real_invs - num_reversals_invs) > 0:
        # even diff
        if abs(num_real_invs - num_reversals_invs) % 2 == 0:
            return True
        else:
            if abs(num_real_invs - num_reversals_invs) == 1:
                return False
            # odd diff
            else:
                return True
    elif num_real_invs - num_reversals_invs == 0:
        return False
```

that pass each `groupby` object as a df into the `func`; assign the boolean results back to the `df`,

```
cluster_id    memo     valid
   1          m        False
   1          n        False
   2          m        False
   2          m        False
   2          n        False
   3          m        True
   3          m        True
   3          m        True
   3          n        True
   4          m        True
   4          n        True
   4          n        True   
   4          n        True
```

Comment: @Valdi_Bo the `df` parameter refers to each groupby object that hoplefully converted to a `df`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apply your function then merge:

```
df.merge(df.groupby('cluster_id').apply(valid_row_dup).to_frame(), on='cluster_id')

    cluster_id memo      0
0            1    m  False
1            1    n  False
2            2    m  False
3            2    m  False
4            2    n  False
5            3    m   True
6            3    m   True
7            3    m   True
8            3    n   True
9            4    m   True
10           4    n   True
11           4    n   True
12           4    n   True
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Chris's answer.
Just wanted to provide a full-fledged solution.

```
df.merge(df.groupby('cluster_id').apply(valid_row_dup).\
    to_frame().reset_index().\
    rename(columns={0:'valid'}),
    on='cluster_id', how='inner')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you define your function slighly other way:

```
def valid_row_dup2(ser):
    num_real_invs = ser[ser == 'm'].size        # Number of 'm'
    num_reversals_invs = ser[ser == 'n'].size   # Number of 'n'
    siz = ser.size                  # Total size
    diff = abs(num_real_invs - num_reversals_invs)
    if num_real_invs == siz:        # Only 'm'
        return True
    elif num_reversals_invs == siz: # Only 'n'
        return False
    elif diff > 0:          # Different number of 'm' and 'n'
        if diff % 2 == 0:   # Even diff
            return True
        elif diff == 1:     # Difference by one
            return False
        else:               # Odd diff, > 1
            return True
    else:                   # Equal number of 'm' and 'n'
        return False
```

You can add the new column as follows:

```
df['valid'] = df.groupby('cluster_id').memo.transform(valid_row_dup2)
```

IMHO this is a simpler solution (no `merge`, you just add a new column).